# Is it safe to naively replace System.currentTimeMillis() with Clock.systemDefaultZone().millis()?

Tags: java, datetime, java-time

Java 8 introduces the [java.time.Clock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Clock.html) interface, which should allow me to mock out system time calls effectively (awesome!).

I'd like to naively replace calls to `System.currentTimeMillis()` with calls to `someClock.millis()`, but it isn't clear to me that these two clocks will actually return the same values in all cases based the caviet given in the `Clock.system*` docs which state that they use "... the best available system clock".  `System.currentTimeMillis()` doesn't specify any similar claims about using the best available clock.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well no, you can't guarantee it will be exactly the same, because

> The system factory methods provide clocks based on the best available system clock. This may use System.currentTimeMillis(), or a higher resolution clock if one is available

So it explicitly states that it may use a better clock, which means it absolutely may be different.

Even if you analyze all existing implementations and discover they're all using `System.currentTimeMillis()` you are explicitly not guaranteed that things will stay that way, so relying on it would be invalid.

Whether that's close enough for your purposes is really down to your application and personal preference.

Answer (score 1):

JDK 9 will have a higher precision clock, see issue [8068730](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8068730). As such, `System.currentTimeMillis()` and `Clock.systemUTC().millis()` may differ. Consider that today, on Windows, the `currentTimeMillis` returns a low-precision value which will almost certainly be better in JDK 9, even at the millisecond level.

One option to guarantee the same behaviour, is to implement the `Clock` class yourself, calling `currentTimeMillis`.

Answer (score 0):

`java.time.SystemClock` implementation of `java.time.Clock` calls `System.currentTimeMillis()` in its `millis()` method, so basically this is the same and eventually all implementations will return time from [gettimeofday](http://linux.die.net/man/2/gettimeofday) system call

Comment: It is `java.time.Clock.SystemClock` :) but it really uses `System.currentTimeMillis()` so there should be no difference at the time being.

Answer (score -1):

The answer lies with this statement:

> .. This may use System.currentTimeMillis(), or a higher resolution clock
>   **if one is available**.

I feel it's safe to do the replacement so that you get the higher resolution clock like `System.nanoTime()` whenever possible.